# Ngx-bootstrap inline datepicker stops working after browser reload (after setting min e max date from store)

Tags: javascript, angular, ngrx, ngx-bootstrap

I'm fairly new to Angular and I'm sitting on this issue for quite a while.

To contextualize, the application calls a microservice every time a page is loaded, retrieving data and storing on state using ngrx forms, to keep what the user sees always in sync with database data.

I have an ngx-bootstrap inline datepicker to select multiple dates from. The solution that I developed works fine in the normal flow of the application, but if a refresh the browser the datepicker stops working (does not call BSValueChange anymore).

Things that I know:

- When the page reloads the observable where I assign the values to the min and max dates initializes before the 'form' data is loaded on its state (therefore the if to check if it is null);
- Also, I'm aware that Angular does not destroy the component on browser reload. I had an issue where a could not reassign an array like this  `this.myArray = []`  and found a workaround splicing all items to empty the array, I think [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Non_configurable_array_element) explains why. So maybe, the initDate and endDate are not getting destroyed on reload and causing some issue (?).
- The min e max dates are correctly assigned after the 'form' loads (on refresh), but the datepicker breaks.

here is my code:

```
  <bs-datepicker-inline 
    [bsValue]="dateSelected" 
    (bsValueChange)="onValueChange($event)"
    [dateCustomClasses]="dateCustomClasses" 
    [bsConfig]="config" 
    [minDate]="initDate" 
    [maxDate]="endDate">
    </bs-datepicker-inline>
```

```
export class SorteioPersonalizadoSelectorComponent implements OnInit {

  initDate: Date;
  endDate: Date;
  notifier = new Subject();

  constructor(private localeService: BsLocaleService,
              private store: Store<{form: FormGroupState<RootForm>, sorteio: FormGroupState<Sorteio>}>) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    defineLocale('pt-br', ptBrLocale);

    this.config = Object.assign({}, {
      locale: 'pt-br',
      showWeekNumbers: false,
      useUtc: false
    });

    window.onbeforeunload = () => {
        this.notifier.next();
        this.notifier.complete();
    };

    this.store.pipe(select(state => state.form), takeUntil(this.notifier)).subscribe(form => {
      if (form != null && form.value.id !== '') {

         //dataInicio and dataFim are stored in state as string values in the format 'yyyy/MM/dd'
         this.initDate = new Date(form.value.participationPeriod.dataInicio);
         this.endDate = new Date(form.value.participationPeriod.dataFim);

       }
    });
 
  }

}
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Do you see any console error?

Comment: unfortunately not